# regex match and split in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an big string of this format:

```
FA dir_name1 file_name1
FA dir_name1 file_name2
FA dir_name2 file_name1
FA dir_name2 file_name2
....
```

I was thinking if we can write an regex expression while doing split which returns me an array consisting of this:

```
["dir_name1/file_name1", "dir_name1/file_name2", "dir_name2/file_name1", "dir_name2/file_name2"]
```

I have tried splitting the big string first and then do regex. It works but can't we do it using easier way?

Any other way to do this?

Comment: That is not an array.

Comment: @sawa How about it now?

Comment: The edit made it okay now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wish to get an array out of string, some split is required.

```
input.scan(/(?<=^FA ).*$/).
      map { |e| e.split.join('/') }
#⇒ [
#   [0] "dir_name1/file_name1",
#   [1] "dir_name1/file_name2",
#   [2] "dir_name2/file_name1",
#   [3] "dir_name2/file_name2"
#  ]
```

It scans the input using positive lookbehind to get the desired result out of the box, splits it by space and joins with a slash.

---

Another way round would be to just split several times:

```
input.
  split($/).
  map { |line| line.split[1..-1].join('/') }
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Btw I do not see it working it ruby 1.8. I see this: 
yFailures.rb:19: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=^FA\s+).*$/

Comment: I am sorry, but it’s XXI century all around. `Ruby 1.8` was obsoleted decades ago.

Comment: What if I would have to do in 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

This should work even in an antediluvian Ruby:

```
input.lines.map { |line| line.strip[2..-1].sub(' ', '/') }
```

You have to do it in two steps, because any function that could split (`split`, `lines`, `scan`) cannot give you the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted try to use Ruby 2.6 [`Object#then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Object.html#method-i-then):

```
input.lines.map { |s| s.split.then { |e| e.last(2).join('/') } }

#=> ["dir_name1/file_name1", "dir_name1/file_name2", "dir_name2/file_name1", "dir_name2/file_name2"]
```